# VBA calling an access query to fill Excel File

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Run-time error '3190'
Too many fields defined

I recieve this error when I click on a button that calls queries in a [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793%28v=office.15%29.aspx):

```
    '------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Creates the excel file in the path passed to it
    ' Returns the path of the file including the file name and extension
    '------------------------------------------------------------
    Function CreateExcelFile(Path As String) As String
        Dim outputFileName As String
        outputFileName = Path & "SummaryTemplate.xlsx"

        Dim Queries(1 To 4) As String
        Queries(1) = "qryProcessAuditScores"    'Audit scores
        Queries(2) = "qryProcessAuditStations"  'Audit Stations
        Queries(3) = "qryProcessNCs"            'Number of NC's
        Queries(4) = "qryProcessAuditCount"     'number of audits from the year

        Dim qry

        For Each qry In Queries
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
                acExport, _
                acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
                qry, _
                outputFileName, _
                True
        Next

        CreateExcelFile = outputFileName 'return the full path
    End Function
```

When I run the queries by hand in Access I recieve no such error. I have tried Compact and Repair Database with no luck. Any other Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Try using `for qry = 1 to 4` and `Queries(qry)` ?

Comment: Alternatively, put a breakpoint on the docmd.transferspreadsheet line, and inspect the value of `qry`

Comment: I tried that just to make sure but that is a looping issue. This is more clearly a calling or query issue, the code is there as a reference to my method, not because I am unsure of it. The strings were present and being passed. The only thing that I am not totally sure on is the DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet but I have looked over that multiple times. Thanks for the thought but that is not it.

Comment: I have a feeling it's a problem with the Excel workbook and not the queries, although I don't know how scalar arrays are supporting For...Each.  Could be the file is already exisitng, because each query is being output to the same file?  It may not know how to handle the overwrite and throwing an error instead.  Even if not, what range is each query writing to?  Without a defined range, I think it would just always be the first in the sheets collection.  I think you need to think hard about the file handling and where the data will end up in those workbooks

Comment: The really annoying part is this worked for a day or two before the error showed up. It worked out with an existing file there, it appended each query result into a new sheet on the workbook named after the query. Each page was just from A1 down taking all the cells it needed (always less than 10 x 10) and it worked beautifly. Also you cannot define a range for an export, only imports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running sql commands to put the queries into tables, ran the TransferSpreadsheet with those tables, and then ran sql commands to drop the tables.